# Getting CPU usage of a process in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to get CPU usage for a specific process..

This code

```
total_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

works great. The number is corresponding to the "CPU usage" number in Windows' [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager).

But the following gives me weird numbers...

```
process_cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "gta_sa");
var process_cpu_usage = (total_cpu_usage.NextValue() / 100) * process_cpu.NextValue();
```

As you can see on the screenshot (instead of "7", I am getting "2,9..").

[image: Processes]

Comment: Have you tried to put sleep for 1 sec between each NetValue() calls.

The first call to NextValue() starts it measuring, and the next call gives some results.
So the trick is to create all your PerformanceCounter objects and immediately call NextValue() for them. Then sleep a second, and call NextValue() for all of them again

Comment: thx, yes I call NetValue() every second..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, the Process\% Processor Time\Instance counter **returns the % of time that the monitored process uses on % User time for a single processor. So the limit is 100% * the number of processors you have.**

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to compute the value that [taskmgr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) displays using perfmon counters. See [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/83823/perfmon-processor-time-vs-task-managers-cpu-usage).

Also remember the percentage of CPU usage is not a fixed value, but a calculated value:

```
((total processor time at time T2) - (total processor time at time T1) / (T2 - T1))
```

This means that the values depend on both T2 and T1, so there might be differences between what you see on task manager and what you compute, if T2 and T1 used by Task Manager are slightly different than T2 and T1 used by your program.

---

If you are interested, I can provide you some code to retrieve this value using P/Invoke. But'll loose the benefits of Performance Counters (such as monitoring remote processes).

Comment: If my CPU usage is 17% and process_cpu_usage is 100% does it means that my process uses all 17%?? And second problem, sometimes I get more than 100% from process_cpu_usage, for example 102%...

Comment: @MarekJavůrek What does `process_cpu.NextValue()` returns? How many CPUs and cores have you on your machine?

Comment: if my CPU load is about 15% and my process uses all 15% then process_cpu.NextValue() returns number like 99 or 100.. tahts why I do this: var process_cpu_usage = (total_cpu_usage.NextValue() / 100) * process_cpu.NextValue(); ... my CPU is i5-2430M

Comment: Nice thx, It seems to be OK when I divide `process_cpu_usage.nextvalue()` by 4 (my i5 CPU has 2 cores but 4 threads) ... so final question is how to get the right number of cores on various PCs/CPUs..

Comment: It seems to be OK.. Now I will be testing on anothers PCs.. (Environment.ProcessorCount seems to be right)

Answer (score 11):

**Dividing by the processor/core count** is what seemed to yield fairly accurate results when comparing against Task Manager.

To save people time:

```
// This will return the process usage as a percent of total processor utilisation.
var processUsage = process_cpu.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
```