# How to tell if an application is busy?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a ui automation client, and so I don't have access to the typical methods like form loaded, etc.

Basically I want a way to determine if the application under test is working or is idle.

I have tried this:

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("AUT");
localByName[0].WaitForInputIdle();
```

This does not block, even though clearly the application is working.

I'm looking for a sure fire way to determine if an application is busy or not. In this case it is a .net application.

Comment: How are you defining idle?  I don't think I have an answer, but the question comes to mind when thinking about multi-threaded applications that may be running things on different threads all the time.  I would assume that you mean that the UI thread is not blocked from your sample code. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @Steve, the app is multi-threaded, those threads are children of the process. I'm ideally looking for a managed / or unmanaged way to determine all work is done.

Comment: If you are trying to automate a specific app and not create a general purpose application, then perhaps naming the worker threads in your code and then querying for their existence would work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/581hfskb.aspx

Comment: Since you're dealing with a separate process, I don't think that this is going to work - imagine there's some `IsProcessBusy` function - it may return `false` to you but, by the time you *act* on that information, the other process has just started an infinite loop and will never be responsive.

Comment: WaitForInputIdle() is one-shot, as soon as the process enters the message loop and calls GetMessage() then you get true.  Generic assumption is that the process is well-behaved and responsive after that.  Being not responsive is fairly well defined since the OS pays attention as well, it replaces the main window of the app with the "Not Responding" ghost window to alert the user after 5 seconds.  You can use IsHungAppWindow() to detect this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the boolean property Responding of a                  System.Diagnostic.Process instance to check if the process is currently responding.
If a process has a high load and the worker process is not seperated in a working-thread than typicaly this valu is FALSE.
But this isnt realy a safe way...

Another way could be to monitor the current CPU-Load of the process.

[Stackoverflow 9259772: Getting CPU usage of a Process in C sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259772/getting-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-c-sharp)